# Prove that $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod p$ if and only if $x \equiv y \pmod p$ or $x \equiv -y \pmod p$. Hint: $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is the exercise verbatim:

An integer *n* is a square modulo *p* if there exists another integer *x*
such that $n \equiv x^2 \pmod p$. Prove that $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod p$ if and only if $x \equiv y \pmod p$ or $x \equiv  -y \pmod p$.
Hint: $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.

This is my attempt to solve it:

If $x \equiv y \pmod p$ then $\displaystyle \frac{x-y}{p} = q_1 \Rightarrow (x-y)=pq_1$.

If $x \equiv -y$ then $\displaystyle \frac {x+y}{p}=q_2 \Rightarrow (x +y)=pq_2$.

Then $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)=(q_1p)\cdot(q_2p)=q_1q_2p^2$

If $p$ is to divide $ x^2-y^2 $ evenly, then it must also divide $q_1q_2p^2$, therefore $\displaystyle \frac {x^2-y^2}{p}=q_1q_2p$.

To satisfy the condition of divisibility by $p$, $q_1q_2p$ must be an integer. Since the assertion to be proven is "Prove that $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod p$ if and only if $x \equiv y \pmod p$ **or** $x \equiv  -y \pmod p$.", we must show that the premise is true if either $q_1$ or $q_2$ is an integer for sure.

Is this line of reasoning correct up until this point?

How to guarantee that **$q_1q_2p$** is an integer?

Comment: $q_1$ and $q_2$ are integers **by their very definition**. Remember, you *created* them because
$$a\equiv b\bmod p\iff a-b\;\text{ is a multiple of }\;p\iff a-b=p\cdot k\,\text{ for some }\textbf{integer }k$$

Comment: However, no one seems to have pointed out that your approach is flawed. You are supposed to be proving a statement of this form: 
$$A\;{\Large\iff}\; (B\;\textsf{ or }\;C)$$
However, your "argument" (even if it were complete) would only show that
$$A\;{\Large\impliedby}\; (B\;\textsf{ and }\;C)$$
(Only one direction, and you are assuming both $B$ and $C$ are true.)
Here,
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \text{“}x^2\equiv y^2\bmod p\text{”}\\
B &= \text{“}x\equiv y\bmod p\text{”}\\
C &= \text{“}x\equiv -y\bmod p\text{”}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I think you have a point. Actually what I wanted was something that forced either $q_1$ or $q_2$ to be an integer but still have the other be something else potentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the theorem : p( a prime) divides the product $ab$ if and only if  p divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$. Now $x^{2} \equiv y^{2}$ mod $p$ if and only if $p$ divides $x^{2}-y^{2}=(x-y)(x+y)$, if and only if $p$ divides $x+y$ or $p$ divides $x-y$ if and only if $x \equiv y$ mod $p$ o $x \equiv -y$ mod p.

Comment: The theorem is called [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: This seems to make sense. For $(x-y)(x+y)$ to be divisible by $p$ it is sufficient to have either $(x-y)$ or $ (x+y)$ being divisible by $p$.

Comment: @aristotle85 Not only sufficient, but necessary too. So you end up with $\iff $.

Comment: @aristotle85 Actually, the 'sufficient' part is thought as trivial, and Euclid's lemma claims the 'necessary' part.

Comment: Hi @mich95 if we have that $x^2=y^2(mod n)$ for $x,y,z \in Z$ then we will get 4 cases?

Answer (score 2):

Definition: $a\equiv b\pmod{\! n}$ iff $n\mid a-b$. Use it repeatedly.

$$x^2\equiv y^2\pmod{\! p}\iff p\mid x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$$

Read about [Euclid's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#Proof_via_B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity), get:

$$\begin{align}\color{\#0bd}\iff ((p\mid x+y)&\ \text{ or }\ (p\mid x-y))\\\iff ((x\equiv -y\pmod{\! p})&\ \text{ or }\ (x\equiv y\pmod{\! p}))\end{align}$$

Euclid's lemma claims $\color{LightGreen}{p\mid ab}\,\color{\#0bd}\Rightarrow\, \color{#4b3}{((p\mid a)\, \text{ or }\, (p\mid b))}$, but I wrote '$\color{\#0bd}\iff$' there because: $$\color{#4b3}{((p\mid a)\text{ or }(p\mid b))}\iff ((a=pa_1)\text{ or }(b=pb_1))$$

for some $a_1,b_1\in\Bbb Z$ by the exact definition of divisibility, and $$\iff ((ab=p(a_1b))\ \text{ or }\ (ab=p(b_1a)))$$

$$\implies  ((p\mid ab)\text{ or }(p\mid ab))\iff \color{LightGreen}{p\mid ab}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, use your hint:

$$x^2 - y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$(x+y)(x-y) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

Clearly, ths is satisfied if $x=y$ or $x=-y$. Because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has no zero divisors, these are the only solutions.

Comment: I didn't really get this explanation. What is the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}_p$? Do you mean to say that $(x+y)(x-y)$ must be equaled to zero? Why?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of integers mod p. This is a commutative ring, so you can factor the polynomial in the usual manner. Because it does not have any zero divisors, you know that there are no extra roots.

Comment: I think this answer is over my head a bit a this point, so I would need some studying.

Answer (score 1):

if $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod p$ then $p \mid x^2 - y^2$ and so  $p \mid (x-y)(x+y)$ And so by euclids lemma , since $p$ is prime then we have $p \mid (x-y)$ or $p \mid (x+y)$ and so $x \equiv y \pmod p$ or $x \equiv -y \pmod p$

On the other hand if $x \equiv y \pmod p$ or $x \equiv -y \pmod p$ then assume that $x \equiv y \pmod p$ which implies that $p \mid x-y$ and so there exists an integer $k$ such that $pk = x-y$ Now you multiply both sides by $(x+y)$ to get $pk(x+y) = x^2 - y^2$ and let $t = k(x+y)$ and so you have that $pt = x^2-y^2$ and so $p \mid x^2 -y^2$ and so you get the result that $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod p$

Same thing you can do if you assume that $x \equiv -y \pmod p$ but you will just multiply by $(x-y)$ instead.